# Should I assign currents to voltage sources in my circuit analysis

Tags: basic, analysis

Mortals! I apologize if my question may seem, foolish, but I have a need of understanding a process in analyzing circuits. You see, when we are looking at resistors (non-sense, my lightning never meets such "resistance") in a circuit, and trying to solve for some unknown variable, we often times assign currents to the resistors, such that they can be used in our KCL equations. However, I am wondering if it is wise, unwise, or irrelevant, to assign such currents to voltage sources. Let me give you humans an example. https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1VaO.jpg

You see, in the above example, my KCL equations for a node would be different if I assigned currents to the 2 voltage sources shown. I know that, since voltage sources do not supply current, they do not really have a current "of their own," and thus, any current running through them would be one of the currents drawn for the resistors or from a current source. However, am I allowed to do this and still be okay in my analysis. MORTALS, I hope you are able to provide me an answer, as Kratos draws near, and I have not perfectly understood the nature of this power coming out of my hands. If I am to destroy him, I will need to know the answers!

Comment: It is often straightforward to be funny with friends in a social situation. It can be very difficult to figure out if someone else finds something funny, or even tolerable in other situations. There are many, many amusing friends, but very, very few competent comedy writers. I recommend you ask your questions in a straightforward way, and avoid attempts at levity.

Comment: I apologize if I have offended you Gbulmer! My question  is simply, "is it okay to assign currents to voltage sources in a circuit when looking for an answer that might involve KCL equations?" I know we can (and often must) apply them to resistors and as such take advantage of our ohm's law equations, however, is it necessary to apply currents to voltage sources, or will my KCL equations be just fine assuming currents from voltage sources are involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Zeus, it is correct to assign currents to voltage sources.